Sound input device (microphone) not picking up sound
I use my laptop for video meetings. The last couple of times my audio input hasn't worked. I updated and restarted the software however when I go to Settings -> Sound , the input activity indicator shows no activity. This problem just started randomly, my builtin microphone was doing fine before. The laptop is iota 360 running on ubuntu 24. I have checked the other thread but it seemed to be quite out of date so I have asked my question here.
When I go to the input section of sound settings it gives me three microphone options and none of them work. Any suggestions? Thanks
edit I instaled pavucontrol and went to input devices where I found my mic. The input detector seems to oscillate continuously (regardless of wether there's noise or not) at this really low level. Would this mean the mic itself is faulty? Its a really new computer so I wouldnt have thought so thats all
UPDATE after lots of fiddling.. today i got a notification saying another software update is available... and hooray! the problems fixed!
2nd update: however the sound then stopped working after the laptop switched into 'low battery mode'. However after restarting it a couple of times everything working again


try unmute ''mic'' in "alsamixer"

no mic option, just master
